# SSH.NET SocketException An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NET to access some folders to show  on my website via SFTP host and port 22.

but it gives me an exception after uploading the function's page to the online host "smarterasp.net"..

```
[SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions]
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Exception callstack please!

Answer (score 1):

Server OS on smarterasp.net that hosts your website has firewall rules to deny Outbound SFTP 22 port connections.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Visual Studio project with a package manifest you may be able to resolve this issue by modifying the capabilities of the package manifest to include "Private Networks (Client & Server)". You can find the package manifest in your project properties.